# ByteBuddy agent test with gradle and JUnit5

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, junit5, byte-buddy

I've faced some weird behavior when I try to test my Java Agent written using ByteBuddy

The agent intercepts annotated methods/classes and profile them, nothing complicated

```
class ByteInstrumentationConfigurer implements BootstrapConfigurer {

    @Override
    void init(...) {
        def instrumentation = ByteBuddyAgent.install()
        new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .type(isAnnotatedWith(TimeProfiling.class))
                .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) ->
                        builder.method(not(isAnnotatedWith(Generated))) //ignore groovy generated methods (getMetaClass, etc.)
                            .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(TimeProfilingInterceptor.class)))
                .with(stdoutToLoggerWriter.withTransformationsOnly())
                .installOn(instrumentation)
```

And I've got some unit tests where I verify that interceptor method was called

```
class TimeProfilingInterceptorTest {

    static MockedStatic<TimeProfilingInterceptor> timeProfilingInterceptorMockedStatic

    static {
        //agent installation happens here
        new ByteInstrumentationConfigurer().init([:], [:])
        timeProfilingInterceptorMockedStatic = mockStatic(TimeProfilingInterceptor, CALLS_REAL_METHODS)
    }
    
    @Test
    void profilingEnabledClassLevelTest() {
        //some mocking for my classes here
        testCallingComponent.callClassLevelComponentMethod()
        timeProfilingInterceptorMockedStatic.verify(()->
                TimeProfilingInterceptor.measureAndLogExecutionTime(any(),any(),any()),times(2))
}
```

And now, when I start this test using from IDEA I see, that 2 my classes were transformed

> [Byte Buddy] TRANSFORM
> com.kmslh.manager.profiling.components.MethodLevelTimeProfilingComponent
> [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2, null, Thread[main,5,main],
> loaded=false]

> [Byte Buddy] TRANSFORM
> com.kmslh.manager.profiling.components.ClassLevelTimeProfilingComponent
> [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2, null, Thread[main,5,main],
> loaded=false]

But if I run this tests using `gradle` test\build task - no classes transformed. If I output full info - i see that classloader in this case is `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteClassLoader`.

> [Byte Buddy] DISCOVERY
> com.kmslh.manager.profiling.components.ClassLevelTimeProfilingComponent$exposedMethod
> [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteClassLoader@3b1a332,
> null, Thread[Test worker,5,main], loaded=false] [Byte Buddy] IGNORE
> com.kmslh.manager.profiling.components.ClassLevelTimeProfilingComponent$exposedMethod
> [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteClassLoader@3b1a332,
> null, Thread[Test worker,5,main], loaded=false] [Byte Buddy] COMPLETE
> com.kmslh.manager.profiling.components.ClassLevelTimeProfilingComponent$exposedMethod
> [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteClassLoader@3b1a332,
> null, Thread[Test worker,5,main], loaded=false]

Not sure is it an issue or not, but I'm out of ideas. Also I've tried to rewrite test to Java - no result.

Any suggestions to try?

**UPD 1**

From what I see - when test started from gradle - no `auxiliary` classes created

**UPD 2**

I run gradle task with `-verbose:class` and see, that my class loaded before starting instrumentation
`[Loaded com.kmslh.manager.profiling.components.ClassLevelTimeProfilingComponent from file:/C:/Users/.../build/classes/groovy/main/]`

When IDEA run tests (it packs it into jar and run jar) - class is loaded after instrumentation

**UPD 3**

> [Loaded com....ClassLevelTimeProfilingComponent from
> file:/C:/Users/../build/classes/groovy/test/]
>
> [Loaded com....ClassLevelTimeProfilingComponent from
> **VM_RedefineClasses**]
>
> [Byte Buddy] TRANSFORM com....ClassLevelTimeProfilingComponent
> [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93, null, Thread[Test
> worker,5,main], loaded=true]
>
> [Loaded com....ClassLevelTimeProfilingComponent$exposedMethod from
> file:/C:/Users/79270/IdeaProjects/kms-trunk/KMS-Manager/build/classes/groovy/test/]

Answer (score 0):

From your log, the Gradle tests run a different class loader than in your example where things work. I assume therefore that your matcher is sensitive to the class loader that is being used. Also, make sure your ignore matcher does not exclude the class loader in the parallel tests.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I also assume that the issue is with class loaders, cause in case with gradle I don't see at all something like `[Byte Buddy] DISCOVERY/IGNORE com.kmslh.manager.profiling.components.MethodLevelTimeProfilingComponent [ .....]`.  I digged a liitle bit deeper, I suppose you are talking about this class loader sentitivity? `ByteBuddyAgent.getInstrumentation().mTransformerManager.mTransformerList[0].mTransformer.transformations[0].matcher -> classLoaderMatcher.matches == true` ? But I'm not sure how to change it correctly. Can you give a liitle more guidance? Thx

Comment: oh, I think I'm wrong, `matches==true` is correct, that means "any class loader", so I don't need to change it

Comment: Have you checked your `ignore` matcher? Maybe your classes are already filtered here.

Comment: Yes, this is not  an issue. I've tried to add `RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORM`, in this case, as I understand - gradle loads class from .class file, then reload it from JVM loaded classes, transform it with ByteBuddy and then (before test) reads class from .class file anyway. I've added output with verbose class loading to 'UPD 3' in original post

Comment: but did the retransformation help? I see a chance that a different class loader prematurely triggers class loading.